GlobalType mapping in Fluent Nhibernate and npgsql
I'm migrating my project to use newest Npgsql library (v 8.0.2). I used this construction to map C# type to the Postgres type:
var nameTranslator = new NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator();;
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapComposite<StockPriceDto>("stock_item_price", nameTranslator);

Now NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper is marked as obsolete, so I would like to find an alternative for it with Fluent NHibernate configuration.
In postgres I have a stock_item_price type which is almost one-to-one mapping with StockPriceDto type properties (the only differerence is naming convention).
In database i have procedure like:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.stock_price_save(list stock_item_price[]) ...

It is called in the code:
command.CommandText = "Call stock_price_save(@list)";
var listParam = command.CreateParameter();
listParam.ParameterName = "list";
listParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Object;
listParam.Value = data; //IList<StockPriceDto>
command.Parameters.Add(listParam);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

It works perfect with NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper. I cannot find the way to map the type StockPriceDto to stock_item_price in Fluent NHibernate. Anyone done it before?
The error is: Writing values of 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[X.StockPriceDto, X, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is not supported for parameters having no NpgsqlDbType or DataTypeName. Try setting one of these values to the expected database type..

As the obsoletion message says, the replacement for GlobalTypeMapper is to use NpgsqlDataSource (please read the docs for more details). NHibernate would have to add support for NpgsqlDataSource - until then you can suppress the obsoletion message and continue to use GlobalTypeMapper.

Yeah, it seems to be a good solution to wait for NHibernate to support NpgsqlDataSource. Perhaps I should submit issue there...
